# Tables related by a combination of two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help design my query. I do not know SQL and have little need or time to learn it.

I want to create a report based on data in TableA and TableB. The combination of two fields in TableA is related to the same combination in TableB. Here's the details:

TableA: MarketData - 
Fields:
   Marketplace,
   ProdID,
   MktID

TableB: ProductData - 
Fields:
   Marketplace,
   ProdID,
   Title

Marketplace + ProdID is the lookup value.

Desired output:
   Marketplace,   ProdID,   MktID,   Title

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are here to HELP solve problems. Not to do the entire job.

Why do you not at least try to provide anything to start with?

Nevertheless, I guess what your looking for looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.Marketplace, 
    a.ProdID, 
    a.MktID, 
    b.Title
FROM
    TableA a
        INNER JOIN
    TableB b ON a.Marketplace = b.Marketplace
        AND a.ProdID = b.ProdID
```

What is done here is an `INNER JOIN` of two tables based on two join conditions (columns Marketplace and ProdID being equal).

The combinations of those columns should be unique for this to work as you intend it to.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I probably went too far in asking for help on the whole problem, but I didn't know where to start. I did try, but I do not know SQL and now that I see the solution, I can assure you that my attempts were laughable.